# Ionic 2 App crashes after splash screen on iOS - how to debug?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have finally managed to install my Ionic 2 app on my iPhone with a development profile.

When I click the app icon it shows the splash screen, asks for Push permission (I am using Push) and then closes immediately. The same happens when I run it on the xCode simulator.

Any ideas where I can start debugging? This is the first time I am trying to deploy on iOS.

Comment: Read the logs in XCode, there will be the reason why he app crashed.

Comment: You just need to read this (It's give me 5 sec) : [here](https://docs.ionic.io/tools/developer/)

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably using "phonegap-plugin-push" plugin to implement this feature. If that's the case then remove this plugin from your app and try to run it. If app doesn't crash then the problem is with the plugin.

Have you checked all the permission to use the push notification as specified in plugin's git page?